# swagger There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405). Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have implemented swagger but its not loading. getting

> Whitelabel Error Page
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

but same code works for other module and it has same configurations

```
Thu Oct 05 07:16:36 GMT 2023 There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405). 
Request method 'GET' not supported
```

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    private static final String BASE_PACKAGE_NAME = "ie.atsr.afm.web.controller";

    @Bean
    public Docket getAllApiToSwagger() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(BASE_PACKAGE_NAME))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ConfigurationProperties("incident")
@PropertySource("classpath:permission.properties")
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityWithoutCsrfConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**",
                "/v2/api-docs",
                "/springfox/**",
                "/configuration/ui",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/configuration/security",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/_twilio/**",
                "/webjars/**",
                "/swagger2-ui.html",
                "/v2/swagger.json",
                "/configuration/**");
    }

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITE_LIST = {
            "/v3/api-docs/**",
            "/swagger-ui/**",
            "/v2/api-docs/**",
            "/swagger-resources/**"
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
            .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITE_LIST).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITE_LIST).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt()
            .jwtAuthenticationConverter(getAuthenticationConverter());

        http.addFilterBefore(addFilter(), BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.headers().cacheControl();
        super.configure(http);
```

controller sample

```java
@RestController
@Api(tags = "IncidentController")
public class IncidentController {
```

note same code working in other module, but in this module getting error like below in logs.

**--executing: Bean(JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter).doFilterInternal()
----requesting user:null
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]**

i want to implement swagger for particular module. same configurations working for one module but not working for other module

Comment: I tried to format your code and logs and error messages properly, but I'm not sure that I got it right, it was confusing me a little. Also the code has syntactical errors (and is incomplete in the sense that it wouldn't even compile, apart from running).

Also please add the request that triggers the error.